# Can a class B inheriting a class A be an aggregate of it?

Tags: class, object, inheritance, design-patterns, aggregation

Can a class "ClassA", of which inherits a class "ClassB", be composed of instances of this same class "ClassB"?

With a concrete example, let's say I am making a social network, and have two classes : "Post" and "Comment"

A Comment is a subtype of Post, but a Post should be an aggregate of Comment.

Is there a classic way to manage the dependencies in this kind of context ?

Comment: "A Comment is a subtype of Post, but a Post should be an aggregate of Comment". That doesn't sound right, or at least there are two different notions of Post that should be handled as separate classes. Is a post anything that can be submitted to the network, or is it specifically a kind of thing that can be commented on?

Comment: For example, maybe `Post` is a superclass of both `Article` and `Comment`, where an `Article` can contain a list of `Comment`s as well.

Comment: Well, to answer your question, a Post and a Comment can both be submitted to the network.

A Post has :
- author : User
- publication_date : datetime
- content : str
- comments : Comment

And presents the following methods :
- set_like()
- set_content()
- set_comment()

And the fact I want a Comment to be a subclass of Post is because it also should have the exact same properties.

I think you are right saying a Post could be a superclass of both Article and Comment. And that an Article can contain a list of Comment...
BUT, a Comment should contain a list of Comment itself !

Comment: Here is how I solved the problem, for now : 
Post and Comment both implement the PostInterface.
The PostInterface presents the previous Post methods (+ set_like(), + set_content(), + get_comments(), + delete())
The Post and Comment must both define the same states (duplication) : date_of_creation and author.

Comment: "A comment should contain a list of comment itself" So each comment has a list of direct replies? It seems like there should still be a stronger distinction between a post and a comment. E.g., a post can contain images, a comment cannot, or a comment cannot exist as a standalone post (it must be attached to a "higher" post), etc.

Comment: That said, there is nothing wrong with an instance of class `B` having an attribute that is a list of instances of its parent class. I'm just questioning whether `B` *should* inherit from `A` here.

Comment: @chepner, You are right. Here is how I finally schematized the situation, based on your suggestions : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/56768236/125821767-028a1b3c-e336-4d24-9ebc-c60cf8a605a6.JPG

Thank you very much for your help